# Calling a showPPM function in C

Tags: c, function, call

I'm confused at how I call the showPPM function in main. If anyone could help me out that would be great!

The purpose of the program is to read in an image file and display the pixel rgb values. So I don't clutter the post, I'm excluding the getPPM function but if it's needed just ask.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_HEIGHT 600
#define MAX_WIDTH 400
#define RGB_COMPONENT_COLOUR

struct PPM {
    char format[4]; //PPM format code
    int height;
    int width; //image pixel height and width
    int max; //max rgb colour value
};


struct PPM_Pixel {
    //Create variables to hold the rgb pixel values
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;
};


struct PPM *getPPM(FILE * file);
void showPPM(struct PPM * image);

int main( void ){

    FILE *file;
    // get image file
    file = fopen("aab(1).ppm", "r");

    //check if a file exists
    if(file == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "File does not exist\n");
        return 0;
    }

    struct PPM *newPPM = getPPM(file);
    fclose(file);
}

void showPPM(struct PPM * image){

    struct PPM_Pixel rgb_array[MAX_HEIGHT][MAX_WIDTH];
    int i;
    int j;

    for(i = 0; i<MAX_HEIGHT; i++){
        for(j = 0; j<MAX_WIDTH; j++){
            struct PPM_Pixel newPPM_Pixel;
            if(fscanf(image, "%d %d %d", &newPPM_Pixel.red, &newPPM_Pixel.green, &newPPM_Pixel.blue) == 3){
                rgb_array[i][j] = newPPM_Pixel;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The same way you called `getPPM`. Just pass the expected pointer to it.

Comment: Could you please give an example? I've tried numerous ways to call it but with no success. I'm fairly new to C.

Comment: You got a `struct PPM *newPPM = ...` returned from `getPPM`. Now you need to call `showPPM` which expects a `struct PPM *` as an argument. Just put 2 and 2 together.

Comment: `struct PPM *newPPM2 = showPPM(struct PPM * image);` like so?

Comment: `showPPM` is declared as `void` meaning it doesn't return anything. Also, when you call a function, you just pass the argument(s), not the complete type (remember `getPPM(file);`?). Try simply `showPPM(newPPM);`.

Comment: oh.... that makes perfect sense. I've been learning C for the past week so that's my excuse. Yeah I've removed the void statement in my program. When I run the program with the `showPPM(newPPM);` it crashes soon after, any ideas why this may be? I've added a print statement at the beginning of the showPPM function but it doesn't show in the terminal, this makes me think it's something to do with the call?

Comment: My advice at this point would be to learn and use the debugger. Step through your code one line at a time, watch what variables change, and figure out why. For a starting point `fscanf(image, "%d %d %d", ...` is wrong on many levels, but that's beyond what fits into a side comment.

Comment: I'll take your advice and read up more on it. I understand that in `fscanf` the first argument needs to be a file, but I'm not sure how to use the file within that function. This program is for a project and I can't alter the function names. It doesn't make sense to me to open the file in the showPPM function because it's already open in the main, so I'm stuck with what to do. I really appreciate your help, thanks very much!

Comment: Going by the function names alone, I guess the file would have been read in `getPPM` and somehow parsed/stored in a `struct PPM`. Then `showPPM` would not need to re-read the file (and as you noted `fscanf` works with files), but rather just do something with the data already stored into that struct. Good luck with this project, and remember that next time it's going to take far less pain and time.

Comment: Will do, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

call `showPPM()` immediately after calling `getPPM()`

Suggest passing the filepointer and a pointer to the PPM struct.

---

from: `http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html`

Each PPM image consists of the following:

```
A two char "magic number" for identifying the file type. 
Whitespace (blanks, TABs, CRs, LFs).
A width, formatted as ASCII characters in decimal.
Whitespace.
A height, again in ASCII decimal.
Whitespace.
The maximum color value (Maxval), again in ASCII decimal. 
    Must be less than 65536 and more than zero.
A single whitespace character (usually a newline).
A raster of Height rows, in order from top to bottom. 
Each row consists of Width pixels, in order from left to right. 
Each pixel is a triplet of red, green, and blue samples, in that order. 
Each sample is represented in pure binary by either 1 or 2 bytes. 
If the Maxval is less than 256, it is 1 byte. Otherwise, it is 2 bytes. 
The most significant byte is first.
```

Given the above format information, writing the code to display the pixel values is relatively simple.

1. read/discard the Maxval field
2. loop until EOF
3. read three values, probably using `scanf()`
4. print the three values, possibly along with a row/column indication
5. goto 2

Note; there are two possible values for the 'magic' number: `P3` and `P6`

For your purposes, check for both values, not just one.

Note: the `P6` format has the values scaled with the `Maxval` field being full scale.  You may or may not want to take that into consideration

Note: if working with the `P6` format, then may want to use the limits of `height*width` to limit the number of pixels displayed rather than looking for EOF.